# Best way to find if a DOM object is visible or not, using mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

What is the best way to find if a DOM object is visible?

Various cases when object is considered not visible:

1. display: none;
2. visibility: hidden;
3. one of the parents has display: none or visibility: hidden
4. Another DOM element is obscuring the queried element (Nice to have, but I can manage 
   without it).
5. Item outside of screen boundaries.

Comment: Similar question (non-framework specific): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704758/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-really-visible-with-javascript

Comment: Indeed it is. Although the nice script below doesn't appear there....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

since its mootools and this got dealt with on the mootools mail list and it is now going to be a part of Element.shortcuts...

```
/*
* Inspired from http://github.com/jeresig/sizzle/commit/7631f9c3f85e5fa72ac51532399cb593c2cdc71f
* and this http://github.com/jeresig/sizzle/commit/5716360040a440041da19823964f96d025ca734b
* and then http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/4512
*/

Element.implement({

  isHidden: function(){
    var w = this.offsetWidth, h = this.offsetHeight,
    force = (this.tagName === 'TR');
    return (w===0 && h===0 && !force) ? true : (w!==0 && h!==0 && !force) ? false : this.getStyle('display') === 'none';
  },

  isVisible: function(){
    return !this.isHidden();
  }

});
```

http://gist.github.com/137880

Answer (score 7):

Stolen from http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/5757:

```
function isVisible(obj)
{
    if (obj == document) return true

    if (!obj) return false
    if (!obj.parentNode) return false
    if (obj.style) {
        if (obj.style.display == 'none') return false
        if (obj.style.visibility == 'hidden') return false
    }

    //Try the computed style in a standard way
    if (window.getComputedStyle) {
        var style = window.getComputedStyle(obj, "")
        if (style.display == 'none') return false
        if (style.visibility == 'hidden') return false
    }

    //Or get the computed style using IE's silly proprietary way
    var style = obj.currentStyle
    if (style) {
        if (style['display'] == 'none') return false
        if (style['visibility'] == 'hidden') return false
    }

    return isVisible(obj.parentNode)
}
```

Comment: Will have to add point 4 and 5 to this script.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the isVisible method given above was [included](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Element/Element.Shortcuts) in the mootools more Element.Shortcuts.

However neither of these methods account for the scroll state of the browser. The following method seems to work pretty well for me for fulfilling requirement #5 stated in the original question.

```
Element.implement({
isFullyVisible: function() {
    if(this.isVisible()) {
        var coord = this.getCoordinates(),
            winScroll = window.getScroll();

        return winScroll.y <= coord.top;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
});
```

Comment: This seems to always return true _unless_ you scroll past the element. But if you're at the top of the page and the footer, for example, is not visible it will still return true.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Checks display and visibility of elements and it's parents
 * @param  DomElement  el
 * @param  boolean isDeep Watch parents? Default is true
 * @return {Boolean}
 *
 * @author Oleksandr Knyga <oleksandrknyga@gmail.com>
 */
function isVisible(el, isDeep) {
    var elIsVisible = true;

    if("undefined" === typeof isDeep) {
        isDeep = true;
    }

    elIsVisible = elIsVisible && el.offsetWidth > 0 && el.offsetHeight > 0;

    if(isDeep && elIsVisible) {

        while('BODY' != el.tagName && elIsVisible) {
            elIsVisible = elIsVisible && 'hidden' != window.getComputedStyle(el).visibility;
            el = el.parentElement;
        }
    }

    return elIsVisible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function isObjVisibile(obj){

        return obj.offsetTop != -1;
    }
</script>


<input type=button onclick="alert(isObjVisibile(document.getElementById('myTest')))" value='is visible'>
<input type=button onclick="document.getElementById('test2').style.display = 'none';" value='hide'>
<div id='test2'>
<div id='myTest'>test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dimitar's solution doesn't work well with the element whose visibility is 'hidden'.

> `hidden`
>
> **The element box is invisible (not drawn), but still affects layout as normal.**

And Luca's solution doesn't work well when the visibility of parent is 'hidden', however, the visibility of child is not.

> `hidden`
>
> **Descendants of the element will be visible if they have visibility set to visible.** The element cannot receive focus (such as when navigating through tab indexes).

So I mixed their answers:

```
function isDisplayed(obj){
    if (window.getComputedStyle(obj, '').visibility === 'hidden')
        return false
    var w = obj.offsetWidth
    var h = obj.offsetHeight
    var force = (this.tagName === 'TR')
    return ! ( (w===0 && h===0 && !force) ? true : (w!==0 && h!==0 && !force) ? false : window.getComputedStyle(obj, '').display  === 'none' )
}
```

However, it still doesn't work well when the element is transparent.