# Javascript/AJAX element-shown event

Tags: javascript, ajax

In javascript is it possible to trigger an action when a element (for example a div) is shown in the screen?

I have an "endless" grid that extends both horizontally and vertically, and I would like to load the elements dynamically using AJAX while the user scrolls.

Thanks

Comment: This question may be of interest as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704758/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-really-visible-with-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check if the scrollbar is near the end with something like this
(i assume you're using jquery):

```
$('#my-container').scroll(function(e) {
  var tolerance = 0;    
  var $el = $(this);
  if ($el[0].scrollTop + $el.height() >= $el[0].scrollHeight - tolerance) {
   // do your ajax stuff
  }
});
```

**EDIT**: you can check if an element is in the viewport with [viewport plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport)
(or better, you can apply the same logic used there to any container other than window)

Comment: Thanks gpilotino, but this would mean to load a full row or column instead of individual elements of the grid. I want to avoid loading a full column as the grid can get very big!

Comment: i think in that case you have to check both horizontal and vertical at the same time. practically you have to check that the "visibile" element scrollTop/Left are inside the viewport (the window.scrollTop/Left/height/width)

Answer (score 1):

You can use document.body.[scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.scrollTop) and document.body.[scrollLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.scrollLeft) to know the position of the scroll.

P.S: gpilotino was faster and actually posted some useful code