# To close the tab when found certain visible word on a webpage

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I am trying to write a tampermoney script that would close a tab when found a certain word or phrase on a webpage. But when I use `document.body.textContent`, the words that are not visible on the page (i.e. cannot find using Ctrl + F) would also be detected by the script. Is there a way that would only look for the visible content?

```
var blacklist = ["Apple"],
    re = new RegExp(blacklist.join('|'), "i");
if (re.test(document.body.textContent)) {
  var win = window.open("","_self");
  win.close();
```

Comment: I believe that is what `innerText` does?

Comment: @SuperStormer you mean replacing `document.body.textContent` by `document.body.innerText` ? I tried, but it would neither detect the visible word nor the non-visible word

Comment: Check this Q/A [How do I get just the visible text with jQuery (or Javascript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846177/how-do-i-get-just-the-visible-text-with-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: @SuperStormer The `innerText` works after I added the `window.onload` function. However, this would take a few seconds before the function could be trigged as the loading of the webpage takes time. Is it possible to trigger the function immediately once the word "Apple" is visible instead of having to wait for the whole page to be loaded?