# jQuery how to insert line break or other character between the .text() of each child element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, csv

I am trying to convert a HTML TABLE element into CSV format.
In scanning the table, I am iterating visible TR elements, then within each one, I am iterating visible TD elements, using the helpful rule from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846177/how-do-i-get-just-the-visible-text-with-jquery-or-javascript): `$(element).("*:not(:has(*)):visible").text()` to retrieve only text from visible elements.

However, if the TD contains multiple elements, each with its own text, there are no spaces or line breaks between the text from these elements.
Therefore, something that originally appeared in two lines, such as

```
<div>First line</div>
<div>Second line</div>
```

would be returned by text() as `First lineSecond line`.

Even if I add line breaks in the original between the DIVs, these are not returned.

How can I return text, but add a line break or any desired character between the text of each element in the selection set? Must I iterate these with the `each()` function instead, appending line break and next element's text to some result, such as:

```
let result = "";
$(element).("*:not(:has(*)):visible").each(function() {
   result += $(this).text() + "\n";
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7ondb0m6/

Comment: Whoever closed my question as already having an answer didn't read it.  The "related" question is not related.

Comment: I am trying to convert an HTML TABLE element into CSV format: that means after scanning data you have to send it to some programming language to make it CSV. Right?So as I have added `<br>`, when it goes to the programming language you can easly change it to new line.

Comment: @alive no that doesn't help.  In order to have new lines in the CSV, you must use \n newline character, not BR tags.

Comment: in php : `str_replace('<br>',"\n",$text);`: https://3v4l.org/Xn8uJ