# Need help to extract the visible text in a Web Page

Tags: javascript, typescript, css-selectors, webdriver-io, webdriver-io-v4

I'm new to WebDriverIO.

I'm now dealing with an issue in which a locator contains the CSS property.

**text-overflow: ellipsis;**

This allows the text in the locator to fit inside the width.

**As an example:**
**"Long live the king"** is written on the locator.

The text will be displayed as **"Long live t..."** after using CSS text-flow.

My concern is, utilising webdriverIO typescript, is there any way to ensure that the option does not contain three dots? Using the CSS text-overflow property

or is there another way to deal with this?

**FYI:** This work is about a dropdown and a list on text init, and I need to test that the whole text is displayed or multiple dots are displayed.

I'm totally new to this I just took an refrence from
[How do I get just the visible text with jQuery (or Javascript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846177/how-do-i-get-just-the-visible-text-with-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.