# Can I determine the current state of the display CSS style for a given element using JS

Tags: javascript, css

I wish to write a simple javascript function that toggles the visibility of a given element. Problem is, immediately after the page load, the initial style is unknown (at least to me). How can I determine what the current value of a given element's display style element is?

Comment: Are you using any frameworks, jquery , MooTools, ExtJS, other, or plain javascript?

Comment: I am not using any frameworks. I'm not averse to the idea generally, but in this specific case, using a framework means throwing out a whole pile of custom code that the frameworks would not replace (GIS, SVG widgets etc), i.e. not worth using a framework only for a single case, and not worth switching over to a framework because I'd have to reimplement too much to work with the underlying changes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the jQuery/Sizzle source-code:

```
elem.offsetWidth > 0 || elem.offsetHeight > 0 // visible
elem.offsetWidth === 0 || elem.offsetHeight === 0  // hidden
```

where `elem` is a DOM element.

Now I'm not entirely sure why they say that an element is *visible* if *either* dimension is bigger than zero. I'd say that both dimensions should be bigger than zero for it to qualify as 'visible', but I trust they know better. (Maybe one null dimension and another non-zero dimension is not even possible within the browser).

**Update:** There's another discussion on the topic and an alternate solution (haven't tried it though): [How do I check if an element is really visible with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704758/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-really-visible-with-javascript)

Comment: This is indeed the new method adopted in jQuery 1.3.2 and greater.  As far as why either element may be non-zero, an element can have 0 width OR 0 height but still have a visible border, and still be technically "visible".

Comment: offsetWidth/offsetHeight should take the borders into account.
Here's a link from the Mozilla Dev Center:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetWidth

Comment: why instead off CSS-display, u r testing offsetWidth n height ?

Comment: @Rakesh because this holds the computed width and height for the element, which is the clearest indicator for visibility -- or specifically the amount of space the element takes on the page. Also, style.display refers to the __inline styles__ (the one you define through the `style` html attribute on the element)

Answer (score 2):

Pure Javascript way, this should work.

```
function getStyle(elementId){
   alert(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(elementId), '').getPropertyValue("display"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getDisplayStyle(elementId){   
 var display = document.getElementById(elementId).style.display;
 alert(display);
}
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it does not take into account the stylesheet value, e.g. if document.getElementById(elemId).style.display is the empty string, the element may still be hidden by a stylesheet, or visible.

Comment: In Firefox 3.6 and IE8, the value of `display` will be an empty string unless you explicitly style the element with a display property.

Answer (score 0):

Measuring offsets will work if you are only looking at the display property,
but a test for **visibility** requires a look into the(browser-dependent) style cascade

```
document.deepCss=function(who, css){
 var val, dv= document.defaultView || window;
 val= who.style[css];
 if(!val){
  if(who.currentStyle) val= who.currentStyle[css];
  else val= dv.getComputedStyle(who,"").getPropertyValue(css);
 }
 return val || "";
}
function isVisible(who){
 return !!(document.deepCss(who,'visibility') != 'hidden' && 
 document.deepCss(who,'display') != 'none');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

using jQuery, assuming your element has an id of myElement:

```
if($("#myElement").is(":visible")){
    // yep, it's visible - handle accordingly
}else{
    // nope, not visible
}
```

Comment: Question made no mention of jQuery

Comment: Yes, but it made mention of JavaScript which is what jQuery is written in. Didn't realize I was confined to the tags used by OP when answering.

Comment: Assuming jQuery is not an option, how does jQuery do it? using jQery just for this seem like overkill

Comment: @sirlark - For **just** this, it is overkill, however if you're doing a lot with javascript, it'll save you a great deal of code and time overall.

Comment: @inkedmn Don't mean to flame, but yes, you generally should confine you answer to things the question mentions in it's body or tags.  If a question was tagged "C++", would you accept and answer written Boost or QT, both of which are written in C++?

Comment: @Nick Craver - agreed, but see response to your above comment

Comment: @inkedmn @meagar - to be fair, I should have specified I'm not using a framework. It's a reasonable assumption these days that noone actually writes in pure JS ;)

Answer (score -1):

No no, jquery is not needed.

IF that's display: none you are after. Else do the same thing with visibility: hidden.

```
 if(mynode.style.display != "none")
    { ..  }
    else
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$(document).ready( function () {
 if $('#id').hasClass('hidden') 
   $('#id').toggelClass('hidden');
);
```

hidden is CSS class to hide element

Comment: I think you have to add JQuery to your project and forget about any future problems... it is simple and easy solution you able to find.

Comment: and also i use ready event (when DOM model is created) so it helps you to prevent error of getting dom element before its created by browser

Comment: You should use the features built in to jQuery rather than add a "hidden" class; this accomplishes the same thing: `$('#id').toggle();`

Comment: toggle using inline style, but i want to use my css hidden... that allows to me change html from this
<div class="gray"> to this <div class="gray hidden"> and back....