# How to create an Infinite Scroll using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
$( "body").scroll( function() {
   $( "#myDiv").load( "test.html");
});
```

With this syntax we can load content into a `div` when the user scrolls. But before inserting into the div I want to make sure that div is in the viewport area when the user scrolls down.

If yes then I would like to load external content into that `div`. Please help me to achieve my goal.

Comment: If you know how heigh the content is you could monitor the amount of pixels scrolled. Although it's probably a bit of an inelagant idea.

Comment: Doing significant work in scroll event handler is a bad idea! How bad? Enough to bring twitter to its knees :) Check out this blog post by John Resig - http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Comment: Have a look at the [viewport plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704758/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-really-visible-with-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $( "body").scroll( function() { 
    if (document.elementFromPoint(x,y) == $("#whatever")) { 
      $( "#myDiv").load( "test.html");
    }
  }
```

Comment: can u please explain what it does if (document.elementFromPoint(x,y) == $("#whatever")) { 
      $( "#myDiv").load( "test.html");
    } how document.elementFromPoint(x,y) will work?

Comment: It returns the element that is under those co-ordinates, relative to the upper-left corner of your browser window/iframe. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.elementFromPoint You can find the position of a DIV by using things such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetTop