# Is it possible to determine when a dom element has come into view?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to determine when a dom element has come into view ?

I would like an event to be raised when an element (e.g div, image) has come into the view of the browser

Is this possible ?

Comment: Do you mean an element that was below the fold? That the user has now scrolled to - hence it is unhidden by the browser chrome?

Answer (score 3):

Where I saw this question? Right, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704758/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-really-visible-with-javascript).

Not exactly the same but might help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an "easy" way to do it. You basically would have to attach a check to the scroll and resize events. You'll need to do all the calculations - height of window, how much it was scrolled, element's offset, and using these you can see if the element has been scrolled to. Couple of potential optimizations would be - only recheck window height on resize, make sure the element has an ID so it's a quick lookup, use a flag if what you want to do is a one time thing, i.e. once it becomes visible and you do what you do stop the checks.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like an event to be raised
>   when an element (e.g div, image) has
>   come into the view of the browser

You can use the [`onload` event](http://javascript.about.com/library/blonload.htm) for that which fires when all images, DOM, frames have loaded into the page :)