# How can I determine whether an element on the page is within the user's current scroll pane?

Tags: javascript, dom, scroll

I'm working on an infinite scroll implementation using IndexedDB. I am at the part where I need to determine the last element visible on the page.

How can I determine whether an element on the page is within the user's current scroll pane? If possible, I  would prefer native JS over libraries or plugins for jQuery.

Comment: You can check this answer out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/jquery-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scroling

Hope it helps.

Comment: possible duplicate: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704758/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-really-visible-with-javascript>

Comment: Yes, agreed this is possible dupe of #1 comment above. Sorry for not seeing sooner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the reluctance to use jQuery plugins, but when there is one that seems to do exactly what you're looking for -  http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport - that's surely the easiest way to go.