# Scroll div listner

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-listener, scrollable

I have a vertically scrollable div, in which n number of images are being mapped each with feedback buttons (useful) or (not useful).

Like

```
<div className="scrollable__div" id="scrollable__div">
        {sliderImages.map((sliderImg) => (
          <>
            <img src={sliderImg} alt="" />
            <div className="btnsSection">
              <Button
                onClick={SliderYesClicked}
                className="greenBtn"
                id="section2__yesBtn"
              >
                Yes
              </Button>
              <Button
                onClick={SliderNoClicked}
                className="redBtn"
                id="section2__noBtn"
              >
                No
              </Button>
            </div>
          </>
        ))}
      </div>
```

I want a specific function to be called when this div scrolled to a specific distance. example

```
element.addEventListener('scroll', callback)
```

This works but I want a quantitative listening of scroll. Like when horizontal scroll of div is greater than x, then call this.

Possibly as

```
    if (scrollableDiv.scrollY >= 100){
   console.log(''Scrolled 100px)
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the number of an element's pixels which are inside the viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685693/get-the-number-of-an-elements-pixels-which-are-inside-the-viewport)

Comment: Yes it is possible and there are different ways. Please explain what have you tried so we can better help you.

Comment: so did you add a scroll event listener to the element?

Comment: [`element.addEventListener('scroll', callback)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event) should work

Comment: I have tried if(scrollableDiv.scrollY >= 200){console.log('Scrolled 200 pxs')}, but It does not worked for me. I am a beginner developer, so i am not even sure element.scrollY even exist or not.

Comment: element.addEventListener('scroll', callback) This works but I want a quantitative listening of scroll. Like when horizontal scroll of div is greater than x, then call this.