# Selenium - Get location after clicking on an anchor

Tags: python, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, anchor

**I'm trying to check** the fact that when I click on an anchor link, some section is really at the top of the browser (I hope I'm making sense here.)

My test looks like that:

```
class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
        self.accept_next_alert = True
        self.driver.set_window_size(1100, 800)
        self.base_url = "http://someurl"

    def test_anchor(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url)
        driver.implicitly_wait(1)
        location = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//section[@id='123123']").location
        print location

        driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("anchor_text").click()
        location = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//section[@id='123123']").location
        print location

        self.assertTrue(False)
```

The assertion is just so I can see my prints. 
What I get from that is that even though I see that the anchor worked, the location dict stays the same. So I guess I'm not using the right feature.

Could you think of another way to check that the click on the anchor had the expected effect? (by either not looking at the location or by looking at the location the right way or else)

Comment: What do you exactly expect after clicking the `anchor`?

Comment: @Saifur The page scrolls to a specific section (`<section id="123123"></section>`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach would be to click the link and assert that the page (or element, part of a page) looks like it should by comparing the screenshots with the help of [`cssneedle`](https://github.com/bfirsh/needle) package:

```
from needle.cases import NeedleTestCase

class Tests(NeedleTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
        self.accept_next_alert = True
        self.driver.set_window_size(1100, 800)
        self.base_url = "http://someurl"

    def test_anchor(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url)
        driver.implicitly_wait(1)

        driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("anchor_text").click()

        self.assertScreenshot('#my_element_id', 'screenshot-file-name')
```

To create the `screenshot-file-name` you need to first run the same tests with `--with-save-baseline` flag:

```
nosetests my_test.py --with-save-baseline
```

Comment: I think I will use this, I have to work on some other tests right now but I will try as soon as I get the time to get back on this issue and accept your answer if it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To check whether an anchor is set to bring the user to the right location, I use two types of tests:

1. Check that the `href` attribute on the `a` element has a value which is '#' concatenated with the `id` of the element to which it is supposed to point. (Yes, I know in general the URL could be much more complicated. I just code my applications so that I **can** perform such a simple test.) This takes care of cases where I have an `a` element that just points to another element, without any special JavaScript processing.
2. For the more complicated cases (for instance, if I intercept the click event before letting the browser scroll the window), I check the location of the element after clicking on it **relative to the viewport**. The problem with the `.location` field is that it is relative to the document and thus does not change with scrolling. You can get a position which is relative to the *viewport* like this:

   ```
   position = driver.execute_script("""
   var rect = arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect();
   return {left: rect.left, top: rect.top};
   """, element)
   ```

   where `element` is the element's whose coordinates you want. The `position` object will be a dictionary with the `"left"` and `"top"` keys corresponding to the `x` and `y` coordinates of your element *relative to the viewport*. If the element is near the top of the viewport then `"top"` will be 0 or close to 0. The fact is that there are sometimes rounding issues from browser to browser or some other factors affecting coordinates so I would not assert whether `"top"` is exactly 0 but I would use a few pixels tolerance either way.

I would not use screenshot comparisons to perform this test as such test would surely fail if I changed the styling of the element(s) of interest, even though in fact there is no problem with the code.

Comment: interesting! will deffinitely try that too

Answer (score 0):

I would say you use `size` which gives the absolute location of the element before click and after click then compare the value. That would be a easiest way to accomplish that.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
e = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//someXpath")
location = e.location
size = e.size
print(location)
print(size)
```

Returns:

```
{'y': 202, 'x': 165}
{'width': 77, 'height': 22}
```

Code directly taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510882/selenium-get-coordinates-or-dimensions-of-element-with-python)

Comment: The thing is location is exactly the same before and after clicking on the anchor. And to me it doesn't make sense since I don't see the section, click on the anchor, now I see it at the top of my browser (it scrolled to the section)... Or I really didn't understand your answer

Comment: I see now what are you trying to do. I don't do anything like that for my testing. I am afraid but `selenium` does not have any internal mechanism to accomplish that. You might have to use some third party tool and compare the image capture before and after. However another possible option is using `JQuery ` `offset()` See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743143/checking-if-an-element-is-really-visible-to-the-user)

Comment: Ok, I was looking into needle for screenshots, might be a good idea, thanks!