# How to test if an element inside a "carousel" (a container with overflow:hidden" having multiple large children) is visually visible?

Tags: javascript, carousel, visibility

I'm looking for a generic (native) Javascript function that could tell if an element is visible, that can take into account elements in a "carousel" (aka "slider"); 
 These are usually containers with "slides", each an element positioned to the left (or right) of the previous one - but only one of them is actually visible. 
An example can be seen in this web page:
http://www.technobuffalo.com/2015/07/22/iphone-7-concept-sports-quad-hd-retina-display-wireless-charging/

**EDIT:** An example for a carousel with 3 slides:

```
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="slide" style="left:0"><img src="..." /></div>
    <div class="slide" style="left:640px"><img src="..." /></div>
    <div class="slide" style="left:1280px"><img src="..." /></div>
</div>

<style>
   .carousel  {
      width: 640px;
      height: 460px;
      overflow: hidden;
   }
   .slide {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
   }

</style>
```

The function should return `false` for the images not directly visible in the carousel.

I've tried numerous techniques suggested in answers in SO to questions regarding visibility detection, amongst them - checking `offsetParent`, `offsetLeft`, `offsetRight`, and using `getComputedStyle` and checking `display`, and more, but all of them return `true` for the invisible images in the carousel.

Comment: include code of what you have tried, with a slideshow to help us help you

Comment: You'll have to define what `visible` is in this context. Are the elements display `none`, are they somehow hidden behind other elements or off the screen etc. Only when you know what "not visible" is, can you figure this out.

Comment: have you seen [this](https://gist.github.com/jasonfarrell/3659166#file-visibility-js)?

Answer (score 0):

A simple example using [boundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), element is visible when `elementLeft === parentLect` or when `elementRight === parentRight`, depends on your situation

```js
let hash = '#one'
let one = document.getElementById('one')
let two = document.getElementById('two')
let three = document.getElementById('three')

function getResult (el) {
  let elementRect = el.getBoundingClientRect()
  let parentRect = el.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect()
  return `
    ${el.id} - visible: ${elementRect.left === parentRect.left || elementRect.right === parentRect.right}`
}

function hashChange() {
  document.querySelector(`${location.hash || hash} .content`).innerHTML = `
    ${getResult(one)}<br>
    ${getResult(two)}<br>
    ${getResult(three)}<br>
  `
}

hashChange()
window.addEventListener('hashchange', hashChange)
```

```css
.carousel {
  display:flex;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

.slide {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-shrink:0;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div id="one" class="slide">
    <div style="flex:1">
      <div>One</div>
      <p class="content" />
    </div>
    <a href="#two">Next</a>
  </div>
  <div id="two" class="slide">
    <div style="flex:1">
      <div>Two</div>
      <p class="content" />
    </div>
    <span>
      <a href="#one">Previous</a>
      <a href="#three">Next</a>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div id="three" class="slide">
    <div style="flex:1">
      <div>Three</div>
      <p class="content" />
    </div>
    <a href="#two">Previous</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Answering my own question.

```
// This function will return true if an element inside a "carousel" is visually invisible.
function isOffsetHidden(elem) {
  if (elem.nodeName == "BODY") return false;
  // find out if any parent of the element has 'overflow:hidden':
  var p = elem, isOverflow = false;
  while ((p=p.parentNode) && p.nodeName!=="BODY") {
    if (window.getComputedStyle(p)['overflow']=="hidden") {
      isOverflow = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (isOverflow) {
    var er = elem.getBoundingClientRect(),
        pr = p.getBoundingClientRect();

    return (er.right < pr.left || er.bottom < pr.top || er.left < pr.right || er.top < pr.bottom);

  }
  return false;
}
```

It works by first trying to find a container with `overflow:hidden`, then if the element is inside a container with `overflow:hidden` and "outside of the bounds" of the container, the function returns `true`.

In the `while` loop we need to stop when the element is `body`, otherwise it will go on until `Document` and will throw an error saying that the argument for `window.getComputedStyle` "does not implement the Element interface".

I'll also re-edit the title of the question to be more specific to the problem.

Comment: In some situations it will be more efficient to "remember" containers with 'overflow:hidden', then simply have a function to test to see if an element is contained within them.