# Determine if element is behind another

Tags: javascript, browser

Is there a way to determine whether elementA is "behind" another element and thus elementA would not be visible to the user?

Obviously it's possible to do with [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context), but the thing is that we do not know which elements we should be looking at. Therefore we would have to iterate through all the elements in DOM and perform stacking context comparison for multiple elements. That is not good in terms of performance.

Here's a jsfiddle. So is there a way to determine that #hidden-element is not visible to the user, because another element is rendered on top of it?

https://jsfiddle.net/b9dek40b/5/

HTML:

```
<div id="covering-element"></div>
<div>
  <div id="hidden-element"></div>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
#covering-element {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: darksalmon;
  text-align: center;
}

#hidden-element {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: deeppink;
}
```

Comment: have you looked at this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704758/how-do-i-check-if-an-element-is-really-visible-with-javascript

Comment: @mrdeadsven nope, but definitely worth testing. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Our solution was to use couple things to determine whether the element is visible and not behind any other elements. Here's the methods we used.

1. [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to check `visibility:hidden` and `display:none`
2. [document.elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint) from multiple points. Most common cases could probably be handled by checking all the corners. Though we needed more points to get more robust results. Corner coordinates can be easily checked with [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

https://jsfiddle.net/k591Lbwu/27/

HTML

```
<div id="covering-element"></div>
<div>
  <div id="hidden-element"></div>
</div>

<button style="margin-top:100px">Check visibility</button>
```

CSS

```
#covering-element {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: darksalmon;
  text-align: center;
}

#hidden-element {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: deeppink;
}
```

JavaScript

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    const element = document.getElementById('hidden-element')
  alert('Visible = '+isVisible(element))
})

function isVisible(element) {
  if(!isVisibleByStyles(element)) return false
  if(isBehindOtherElement(element)) return false
  return true
}

function isVisibleByStyles(element) {
    const styles = window.getComputedStyle(element)
  return styles.visibility !== 'hidden' && styles.display !== 'none'
}

function isBehindOtherElement(element) {
  const boundingRect = element.getBoundingClientRect()
  // adjust coordinates to get more accurate results
  const left = boundingRect.left + 1
  const right = boundingRect.right - 1
  const top = boundingRect.top + 1
  const bottom = boundingRect.bottom - 1
  
  if(!element.contains(document.elementFromPoint(left, top))) return true
  if(!element.contains(document.elementFromPoint(right, top))) return true
  if(!element.contains(document.elementFromPoint(left, bottom))) return true
  if(!element.contains(document.elementFromPoint(right, bottom))) return true
  
  return false
}
```

Note: [Node.contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) returns true if the given element is the node itself or a descendant of it. If you want to check for only the exact element instead of including also it's descendants, you should use `document.elementFromPoint(...) !== element` for the conditional statements inside `isBehindOtherElement`

Comment: This doesn't work. your solution seems to only determine if both elements overlap but does not take into account z-index for example. So the checked element might be visible but would still return false in many scenarios.

Comment: @EricUldall it does work with z-index too, you can try it out in the jsfiddle provided in the answer. Add another element inside #covering-element and play around with #hidden-element and the new element z-index values. Remember to set e.g. `position: absolute` to make z-index count. (template: https://jsfiddle.net/9hg063k4/14/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yptsdo54/ This only took me a few seconds to break.

Comment: Did you post the correct link @EricUldall? Looks like the #hidden-element is covering the #covering-element in your jsfiddle

Comment: Thats correct. The #hidden-element is not hidden. so when checking if hidden element is visible it should be true but your code returns false.

Comment: Works fine for me, with your example and no modifications. Hope you'll find out why it doesn't work for you. Maybe try with different browsers or something 

Comment: so when you run my fiddle and click 'check visibility' it alerts Visible = true ?

Comment: Ah , I found the issue, if any part of the element is off the screen you get visible = false. Just shrink the window a bit and scroll down so a small edge of the pink square is off screen. Then it breaks.

Comment: Oh, but then it is working as intended. If you want to have partially visible (due to partially off-screen) detected as visible, then you should tune the coordinates and points a bit

Comment: ye I guess it's a semantic issue. To me isVisible means, can a human viewing the page see it. As opposed to being invisible. I guess what your code really tells us is: isUnobstructed

Comment: Yep, well the `isVisible` function is after all checking `isVisibleByStyles` and `isBehindOtherElement`

Comment: Great answer. One small thing: Inside `isBehindOtherElement`, it might be better to use `element.contains(document.elementFromPoint(...))` as opposed to `... !== element`. Because `document.elementFromPoint` could potentially return a descendant of `element`.

Comment: Thanks @AradAlvand, you are right, Node.contains is most likely a better option for most of the use cases. I edited the answer based on this 