# Does Intersector Observer works with Z-indexes?

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I am trying to create a frontend logic here, and the requirement is as follows -:

1. There are 4 UI elements on the screen.
2. On certian device resolutions, some of these UI elements overflow outside of the screen or get hidden behind the main header component.
3. I want to prompt the user to change the zoom level of the browser till all of the 4 UI elements are completely visible in their respective position or not.

Initially, I thought of using the Intersection Observer to check the Intersection Ratio of the 4 UI elements. But, I am confused if the intersections observer works when elements are hidden visually, but present on the screen DOM wise?

Answer (score 0):

You are basically asking two questions:

> [how to detect when some element] **overflow outside** of the screen [or offsetParent…]

That's exactly what [intersection observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) is for.

> [...] or get **hidden behind** [other positioned element].

Sadly, there is no top-level native API similar to intersection observer for this.
You can only query *"what is the topmost element on given coordinates"* with [`elementFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint).

So technically it is possible to detect if some element is (partially) obscured by other element, and what obscures it, with combinations of [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) (or `getClientRects`) and `elementFromPoint`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1542908/540955 for a simple POC.